# Cannot crop PNG images using cropper js

Tags: javascript, image, png, crop, cropper

I am using [cropperjs](https://github.com/nigelsmk/cropperjs) to crop images and upload them. I can crop JPEG images but not PNG images currently. For both JPEG and PNG images, the img tag shows the base64 string in the console after I crop.

For JPEG images after I crop and hover over the image, I can see the image.

However, when I hover over the base64 string for the PNG cropped image, there is no image shown. What I see is this:

[PNG cropped image base64 string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL0ba.png)

This is how I crop the image:

```
 var image = document.getElementById('blah');
    var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio : 1 / 1,
        crop : function(e) {
            console.log(e.detail.x);
            console.log(e.detail.y);
    }
});

var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/png');
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imgurl;
img.setAttribute("id", "blah");
```

I have tried

```
var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

and

```
var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/*');
```

too. 
My input type is:

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
```

I have tried

```
var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/png');
```

and

```
var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
```

too. 
Please help or advise me, I have searched many links for help and tried several ways to fix this.

Comment: what version of cropper are you using?

Comment: please, use `getCroppedCanvas().toBlob`

Comment: @Endless getCroppedCanvas().toBlob is to get the blob from the canvas so that the blob can be uploaded to server. now i simply want to display the cropped PNG image to user, before even converting to blob and before uploading to server.

Comment: Well, to show the blob to the user, just use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` that is better then base64